# delaying picture capture in AVCam demo

Tags: ios, nstimer, avcam

Using the [AVCam demo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html), I'm trying to add a delay of 5 seconds before the picture is actually taken by making the following changes in AVCamViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)captureStillImage:(id)sender
{
    // Capture a still image
    [[self stillButton] setEnabled:NO];

    // delay picture capture by 5 seconds
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 5.0                                                
        target: self                                                  
        selector: @selector(pictureTimer:)                                          
        userInfo: nil                                                
        repeats: NO];
}

- (void) pictureTimer: (NSTimer *) timer {
    [[self captureManager] captureStillImage];
}
```

However, the completion handler in AVCamCaptureManager::captureStillImage never seems to get called (I never see the "captureStillImage completion handler" log message):

```
- (void) captureStillImage
{
    AVCaptureConnection *stillImageConnection = [AVCamUtilities connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo fromConnections:[[self stillImageOutput] connections]];
    if ([stillImageConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
        [stillImageConnection setVideoOrientation:orientation];

    NSLog(@"captureStillImage");
    [[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:stillImageConnection
         completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"captureStillImage completion handler");
```

Will this just not work using an NSTimer?

Comment: is any runtime error being printed out in your console? Is your "pictureTimer:" method declared in your "`@interface`" file?

Comment: No there are no runtime errors that I see. It is declared in the interface file.